# Cell padding accurate in Gmail, but not in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: css, email, outlook, phpmailer, html-table

I have a php email that is received by our company's email client, microsoft outlook. I also get a copy in my gmail. Everything looks fine in gmail:

This php / html:

```
$remainder = <<<EOD

<tr>
    <td colspan='2' style='font-size:12pt; padding:5px 0px 5px 3px; background-color:#F7F7F7;'>
    Product details
    </td>
</td>


<tr>
    <td style="width:150px;font-size:10pt; padding:10px 8px 0px 3px;" align="left">
        Product type:
    </td>

    <td style='font-size:10pt; padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;'>
        {$product}
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td style='width:150px;font-size:10pt; padding:10px 8px 0px 3px;' align="left">
        Quantity:
    </td>

    <td style='font-size:10pt; padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;'>
        {$qty}
    </td>
</tr>       



<tr>
    <td style='width:150px;font-size:10pt; padding:10px 8px 0px 3px;' align="left">
        Product size:
    </td>

    <td style='font-size:10pt; padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;'>
        {$productSize}
    </td>
</tr>



<tr>
    <td style='width:150px;font-size:10pt; padding:30px 8px 0px 3px;' align="left">
        Account executive:
    </td>

    <td style='font-size:10pt; padding:30px 0px 0px 0px;'>
        {$accountExec}
    </td>
</tr>
```

produces something that looks like this in gmail: (minus the part at the top i didn't crop)

[image: gmail screenshot]

However, in microsoft outlook, I get something that looks like this (with much inflated padding.

I can see by looking at the elements in the browser (when I forward the element back to gmail from msOutlook) that several different elements are being added. Why would this happen? Is there anyway to prevent it?

[image: explanation of html in chrome console]

[image: ms outlook printout]

How could I make this so it looks right in both?

Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft Exchange is a server. You mean Microsoft Outlook, the client?

Comment: HTML in email is always really tricky - some mail clients intentionally ignore paddings, margins an absolute positionings to prevent you moving an element outside the normal display area - You may well find this is a case of trial and error

Comment: @JustinPearce I persistently made that mistake throughout the post. thanks for the correction! MS outlook is what i mean... ><

Comment: @Basic How would you recommend sending email then?

Comment: @thomas I can't give you a good answer - there's a reason a lot of the SPAM emails you get have a "Can't see this email properly? View it online" link in them - It's just not possible to render HTML email consistently across all possible mail clients with anything but the simplest layouts. If I were you, I'd try wrapping the elements in `div`, `span`, perhaps removing the ones you've already go, etc... I'd also try removing `class` attributes from elements and using inline styles. But as I said, it really is trial and error - and then you need to test in Hotmail, Y!, thunderbird, etc, etc, etc

Comment: @Basic oki doke will do. the div thing is working ... sort of. I think the view online solution is a good one as well. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest wrapping the content of every table cell in a div and give the padding to that div and not the td